# DD4T 2 with CIL: Page Not found on startup

Tags: dd4t

I am experimenting with DD4T 2. I'm getting the the latest alphas of everything from NuGet, and I've selected Autofac as my DI system.

When I start the application with a request for `/`, I get an exception, which appears to be thrown from the following code in `TridionControllerBase`.

```
[HandleError]
public virtual ActionResult Page(string url)
{
    url = AddWelcomePageToUrl(url);
    IPage page = GetPage(url);
    if (page == null) { throw new HttpException(404, "Page cannot be found"); }
    return View(GetViewName(page), page);
}
```

In the broker database, my root page is `index.aspx`. I have tried adding a `DD4T.WelcomeFile` appSetting, but this doesn't help.
My debugging session is a bit iffy, but it's fairly clear that `page` is evaluating to null. (`url` is already null by the time my PageController gets invoked.) What might be the cause of this, and how can I further investigate?

Comment: How about some info around the basics, what does `url` contain at the time of this request, and is there a corresponding page in the broker for that?

Comment: Not 100% sure how DD4T handles this, but I guess if `url` is null, then `AddWelcomePageToUrl(url)` hopefully turns that into `index.aspx`. But without debugging working it's not really precision guess work, so not my cup of tea ;o). Maybe add another question about your issues with debugging, surely that shouldn't be so difficult to setup?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was with connecting to the content service. I had configured the discovery service url in my `web.config`, but it turns out that you need various `oauth-client-` settings as well.

I also needed to specify `DD4T.WelcomeFile` and `DD4T.PublicationId`. Here is the relevant part of my web.config

```
<add key="DD4T.WelcomeFile" value="index.aspx" />
<add key="DD4T.PublicationId" value="15" />
<add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://dd4t.local:8082/discovery.svc" />
<add key="cid-service-proxy-pattern" value="/cid*" />
<add key="service-caching" value="false" />
<add key="service-caching-expiration" value="60" />
<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true" />
<add key="oauth-client-id" value="cduser" />
<add key="oauth-client-secret" value="CDUserP@ssw0rd" />
```

(Note that as it's my own dev server I am running the microservices with the out-of-the-box security configuration, so you don't need to worry that I'm disclosing highly secure passwords!)

Comment: Your passwords are showing! :)

Comment: I already mentioned that these are the OOTB passwords. Nothing to worry about. Thanks.